# C++ program isn't recognizing that {-1, 0, 1} is a group

Tags: c++

So I have a function that looks at whether a given set and an operator forms a Group. The definition of a group is as follows:

```
         A set  S is a group if and only if all the 4 following
         conditions are true: 
        (1) If a, b in S, then a op b in S
        (2) If a, b, c in S, then (a op b) op c = a op (b op c)
        (3) There is an element 0 in S such that a op 0 = 0 for all a in S
        (4) If a in S, then there is a b in S such that a op b = b op a = 0
```

By this definition, the set `{-1, 0, 1}` with operator `*` should be a group with identity element `0`.

However, my implementation of a Group-checking function isn't working. My code

```
template <typename ObType, typename BinaryFunction>
bool isGroup(const std::set<ObType> & S, BinaryFunction & op, ObType iden)
{
    /*
       isGroup returns true or false depending on whether the set S
       along with the operator op is a group in the Algebraic sense.
       That is, S is a group if and only if all the 4 following
       conditions are true: 
            (1) If a, b in S, then a op b in S
            (2) If a, b, c in S, then (a op b) op c = a op (b op c)
            (3) There is an element 0 in S such that a op 0 = 0 for all a in S
            (4) If a in S, then there is a b in S such that a op b = b op a = 0
    */
    typename std::set<ObType>::const_iterator beg(S.cbegin()), offend(S.cend());
    bool noProblemsYet(true), foundIdentity(false);
    for (typename std::set<ObType>::const_iterator ia = beg; ia != offend && noProblemsYet; ++ia)
    {
        bool isIdentity = true;
        for (typename std::set<ObType>::const_iterator ib = beg; ib != offend && noProblemsYet; ++ib)
        {
            // ---------- (1) --------------
            if (S.count(op(*ia, *ib)) == 0)
                noProblemsYet = false;
            // ---------- (3) --------------
            if (op(*ia, *ib) != op(*ib, *ia) || op(*ib, *ia) != *ib)
                isIdentity = false;
            // -----------------------------
            for (typename std::set<ObType>::const_iterator ic = beg; ic != offend && noProblemsYet; ++ic)
            {
                // ---------- (2) -------------
                if (op(op(*ia, *ib), *ic) != op(*ia, op(*ib, *ic)))
                    noProblemsYet = false;
                // ----------------------------
            }
        }
        if (isIdentity)
        {
            foundIdentity = true;
            iden = *ia;
        }
    }

    if (noProblemsYet)
    {
        if (!foundIdentity)
            noProblemsYet = false;
        for (typename std::set<ObType>::const_iterator ia = beg; ia != offend && noProblemsYet; ++ia)
        {
            bool foundInverse = false;
            for (typename std::set<ObType>::const_iterator ib = beg; ib != offend && noProblemsYet; ++ib)
            {
                if (op(*ia, *ib) == op(*ib, *ia) && op(*ia, *ib) == iden)
                {
                    foundInverse = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // ---------- (4) -------------
            if (!foundInverse)
                noProblemsYet = false;
            // ----------------------------
        }
    }

    return noProblemsYet;
}

template <typename T>
class Multiplier
{
    private:
        static const char symbol = '*';
    public:
        T operator() (const T & x, const T & y) const { return x * y; };
        char getSymbol(void) const { return symbol; };
};

template <typename T>
std::string set2Str(const std::set<T> & S)
{
    std::string retstr = "{";
    typename std::set<T>::const_iterator it(S.cbegin()), offend(S.cend());
    if (it != offend)
        retstr.append(std::to_string(*it++));
    while (it != offend)
        retstr.append("," + std::to_string(*it++));
    retstr.push_back('}');
    return retstr;
}

int main()
{
    std::set<int> S = { 0, 1, -1 };
    Multiplier<int> m;
    int i;
    std::cout << set2Str(S) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "with operator " << m.getSymbol() << std::endl;
    if (isGroup(S, m, i))
        std::cout << "is a group, with identity element " << i;
    else
        std::cout << "is not a group.";
        return 0;
}
```

is, for some reason, outputting

```
{-1,0,1}
is not a group.
```

Any idea why this might be?

Comment: How about doing one check per function and then you can easily see which of those is giving an incorrect result.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what an identity element is... (also 0 has no inverse)

Comment: Seems like stepping through it in the debugger would help you figure out where it is going wrong.

Comment: SO is not a "we-debug-while-u-wait" service.

Comment: The identity ("0") element depends on the operation, and is the number zero (0) for addition, while for multiplication it is one (1). (In other words, "0" in the definition is just a name, not a number.) And your rule 3 is wrong, it should be `a op 0 = a`.

Answer (score 2):

Your definition of a group is incorrect.

The line

```
    (3) There is an element 0 in S such that a op 0 = 0 for all a in S
```

should be

```
    (3) There is an element 0 in S such that a op 0 = a for all a in S
```

The set {-1, 0, +1} does not form a group under the operation of multiplication.

The number +1 does act as an identity element for this set, but the number 0 has no inverse, which is required by

```
   (4) If a in S, then there is a b in S such that a op b = b op a = 0
```

The set {-1, +1} *does* form a group under multiplication.

Comment: Because it violates (4), not because it violates (3). The multiplicative identity is `1`, but not every element has a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: That's true.  Two unrelated wrongs.  I'll add a note.